# How can I know if an additional edit is going to turn my answer into an open community-wiki (CW)?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I have had a nice and pedagogical idea to add to [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/how-can-the-speed-of-light-be-a-dimensionless-constant/52980#52980) but I am afraid that, by doing an additional edit now, it may turn into a wiki-thing, as once happened.

I just want to do one additional edit. How can I know that? Yes, I know it is the policy of this site, but I prefer (as a personal taste I am not interested in discussing) not to edit it any more if it is going to be converted into an open answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) .

Yep, it will turn into CW at your next edit. Don't worry, if you want to un-CW-ify it just flag it (or reply to this post). CW is only when you want collaboration, just let us know whenever you get hit on the head with the 10-edit thing :)

However, try to batch up your edits, constant bumping to the main page isn't something we really want -- leads to clutter.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at [the edit history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/52980/revisions) (get there by clicking the time stamp on the "edited" block beside your usercard) and compare to [the rules for automatic how community wiki works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/2509).

In this instance it appears that a further edit *will* tip your answer into wiki status.